# MIPS Architecture data access

Tags: mips

I have a problem with MIPS architecture.

I need to calculate code-size and data access for this piece of code.
I know that

> opcode =1 bytes
>
> memory adress length =2 bytes lengths
>
> all data operands =4 bytes lengths

My code solve this equation: y=(A-B) / (C + D*C)

```
LD $S1, d($t1)
LD $S2, e($t1)
MPY $S1,$S2,$S1
LD $S2,C($T1)
ADD $S1,$S2,$S1
LD $S2, a($tS1)
LD $S3 ,b($t1)
SUB $S2,$S2,$S3
DIV $S1,$S2,$S2
ST Y($T1),$S1`
```

Comment: can you help me please??

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Surely you could calculate the code size easily since the instructions have a fixed length? And what kind of MIPS processor is this that has an `MPY` instruction?

Comment: It is Load/store machine.I wrote assembly program and i want to compare the storage requirements(code size) and total # of byte accesses required in execution (for instruction fetch and data read/write).

Answer (score 0):

The first step to do is to check which are "real instructions" and which are pseudo-instructions.

When you compile your code, your instructions 
For example, from [here](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) you can find a full list of instructions in MIPS, and from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Pseudoinstructions) you can find a list of pseudoinstructions.

In your code you can find `ADD & SUB` that are real instructions, so 32bits each.

I suppose your `MPY` stands for `MUL`, which is again a real instructions, so 32bits again.

`DIV` is an instruction formed by two assignment (one for the quotient one for remainder), so 64 bits.

I suppose, from your code and your meanings, that `LD` stands for `LB`, which is a single-line instructions, 32 bits.

Giving these assumptions,

```
LD $S1, d($t1)      32 bit
LD $S2, e($t1)      32 bit
MPY $S1,$S2,$S1     32 bit
LD $S2,C($T1)       32 bit
ADD $S1,$S2,$S1     32 bit
LD $S2, a($tS1)     32 bit
LD $S3 ,b($t1)      32 bit
SUB $S2,$S2,$S3     32 bit
DIV $S1,$S2,$S2     64 bit
ST Y($T1),$S1       32 bit
```

I'm not sure about my assumptions, but if they are not correct, that's anyway the correct way to find your code-size.